# Android.....progress bar

Tags: android

How to put ProgressBar between screens in Android?

Answer (score 1):

First call progress bar logic when calling second screen and then load second screen.

Find progress bar examples [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html)